Access IPv6 website having a scope on chrome
I'm encountering difficulties accessing an IPv6 website with the address fe80::6aa3:78ff:fe63:3c2a, which includes a scope identifier (%22), using Chrome.
I've attempted accessing it via http://[fe80::6aa3:78ff:fe63:3c2a]/, but it's timing out (similarly, ping requests are also timing out), indicating the necessity to specify the scope in the address. I've experimented with both http://[fe80::6aa3:78ff:fe63:3c2a%22] and http://[fe80::6aa3:78ff:fe63:3c2a%2522], following the suggestion in this answer 10448106, yet neither form is accepted as a correct address.
Notably, wget http://[fe80::6aa3:78ff:fe63:3c2a%22] successfully retrieves the HTML content.
Could someone advise on the correct method to access an IPv6 website with a scope identifier in Chrome or Mozilla?

You may need to escape the %. Also, some browsers do not support Link-local addressing. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1
